# Craft as IdP using Saml Identity Provider Plugin

Tags: plugins

I'm running Craft CMS Pro v3.9.1.

We're trying to interface a Craft site with a partner site. The idea being that the user logs into our site with their Craft credentials then, if needed, click a link on the page to the partner site and be logged in via SSO with their Craft creds.

We've installed the SAML Identity Provider plugin in Craft and added Craft as the identity provider. We traded metadata with our partner and have them added as a service provider in Craft. As far as we know, they've correctly added us on their side.

So, we login to our Craft site, click the link to connect to the partner site and get a page of error messages.
The main error at the top is:

Argument 2 passed to flipbox\saml\idp\services\messages\Response::create() must be an instance of flipbox\saml\idp\records\ProviderRecord, null given, called in /home/site/wwwroot/vendor/flipboxfactory/saml-idp/src/controllers/LoginController.php on line 79

Sorry, I'll figure out how to add the entire error page shortly.

EDIT: Full error:  https://pastebin.mozilla.org/0NPRtQ2z

I can't decipher from that whether that's an issue on our side or the partner side.  Or, maybe it's that what we're trying to do just isn't meant to work.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thanks,
Robin

Comment: same problem here.

Comment: @good_afternoon
For us, it turned out to be an error in the Default Entity ID of the plug-in settings.  Instead of https://site.com/ it was entered as https://site.com/web.  Once 'web' was removed, and the metadata regenerated/uploaded, everything started working fine.
Hope that helps. - Robin

Comment: For some reason the default entity id "my-site.ddev.site" messed it up. I removed the url format and made the id something like "my-site" and it "fixed" it. weird. thanks for your help! can't say i'd feel comfortable spending $200 on this plugin and using it on a production website though. littered with 500 errors and no documentation.